# .Net MVC http request data loading time take 20 to 30 min (need to optimize to less than 2 min)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I am calculating the salary of employees. there are multiple calculations in this request e.g. monthly working hours, total duty hours, total late hours, loan balance, advance balance, overtime calculation, gate passes calculation etc.** this request takes 20 to 30 min for 500 employees.**

## I have .NET C# web application in **.net4.8 with MVC Structure and ORACLE database.**

What can I do to optimise this request?

```cs
var items = dbMEMBERs.Where(m => {
  return
    (MemberType != 0 ? m.STATUS == MemberType : true) &&
    (MemberId != 0 ? m.ID == MemberId : true) &&
    (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Gender) ? !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.GENDER) && m  .GENDER == Gender : true) &&
    (DEP_ID != 0 ? m.DEPT_ID == DEP_ID : true) &&
    ((IsDirectorSalary == 1 ? (m.STATUS == Constants.MemberTypes.Director ||
        m.STATUS == Constants.MemberTypes.Employee) : (m.STATUS == Constants.MemberTypes.Employee) || (m.STATUS == Constants.MemberTypes.Terminated && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.DischargeDate) >= firstDayOfMonth))) &&
        m.SALARY_TYPE == Constants.SalaryTypes.Monthely &&
    DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.JOIN_DATE) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(lastDayOfMonth) &&
    (MemberStatus != 0 ? m.MemberStatus == MemberStatus : true)
});

ListMemSal = (from mem in items join dept in dbDEPARTMENTs on mem.DEPT_ID equals dept.DEP_ID
  //where dept.DEP_ID == DEP_ID
  from sal in dbSALARies.Where(m => m.MEMBER_ID == mem.ID && m.ISSUED_DATE == _date).DefaultIfEmpty() from Attendance in dbMemberAttendance.Where(m => m.MemberID == mem.MACHINEID && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.AttendanceDate) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(firstDayOfMonth) && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.AttendanceDate) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(lastDayOfMonth)).DefaultIfEmpty()
  //from overtime in dbOVERTIMEs.Where(m => m.MEMBER_ID == mem.ID && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.OVERTIME_DATE) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(firstDayOfMonth) && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.OVERTIME_DATE) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(lastDayOfMonth)).DefaultIfEmpty()
  // from gatepass in dbMEMBERS_GATEPASS.Where(m => m.MEMBER_ID == mem.ID && m.STATUS == 1 && m.PURPOSE == 2 && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.GatePassDate) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(firstDayOfMonth) && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.GatePassDate) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(lastDayOfMonth)).DefaultIfEmpty()
  select new ViewofSalary {
    MEMBER_ID = mem.ID,
      MACHINEID = mem.MACHINEID,
      MemberStatus = mem.STATUS,
      Full_Name = mem.FIRST_NAME + (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mem.Relation) ? " " + mem.Relation + " " : " ") + mem.LAST_NAME,
      Salary = mem.CURRENT_SALARY ?? 0,
      Attendance_ID = Attendance.ID,
      Working_Hours = Attendance.PayableHours,
      ISSUED_DATE = Attendance.AttendanceDate,
      TAX = mem.TAX ?? 0,
      //OverTimeHours = overtime.OVERTIME_HOURS,
      //OverTime_Date = overtime.OVERTIME_DATE,
      // Rate = overtime.Rate ?? 0,
      // OverTimeID = overtime.ID,
      //OverTimeStatus = overtime.STATUS,                                      
      STATUS = Attendance.Status,
      SalaryStatus = sal.STATUS,
      AdvanceAmountSalary = sal.ADVANCE_AMOUNT ?? 0,
      LoanAmountSalary = sal.LOAN_AMOUNT ?? 0,
      SalaryAmountSalary = sal.AMOUNT,
      EOBI_AMOUNT = mem.EOBIAmount ?? 0,
      UNIFORM_EXPENCE_AMOUNT = sal.UNIFORM_EXPENCE_AMOUNT ?? 0,
      SAL_ID = sal.ID,
      // GatePassHours = gatepass.GatePassHours,
      // GatePassID = gatepass.ID,
      Date = Attendance.AttendanceDate,
      SavedSalary = sal.BASIC_SALARY ?? 0,
      Leaves = sal.LEAVES,
      Absents = sal.ABSENTS,
      workingDays = sal.WORKING_DAYS,
      WorkingHours = sal.WORKING_HOURS,
      Current_Sallary = sal.SALARY1 ?? 0,
      DeductionHours = sal.DeductionHours,
      deductamount = sal.DEDUCTION ?? 0,
      EOBI_AmountSalary = sal.EOBI_AMOUNT ?? 0,
      TaxSalary = sal.TAX ?? 0,
      OtherFineDeductionSalary = sal.OtherFineDeduction ?? 0,
      GatePassDeduction = sal.GatePassDeduction ?? 0,
      OverTimeHoursSalary = sal.OVERTIME_HOURS_SINGLE,

  }).OrderBy(m => m.AdvBonusDate).ToList();

if (ListMemSal != null && ListMemSal.Count > 0) {
  //  ListMemSal = ListMemSal.Where(m => (MemberId != 0 ? m.MEMBER_ID == MemberId : true) && (DEP_ID != 0 ? m.DEP_ID == DEP_ID : true)).ToList();
  if (Type == 4) {
    ListMemSal = ListMemSal.Where(m => m.SAL_ID == 0).OrderBy(m => m.Member_Code).ToList();
  }
  if (Type == 2) {
    ListMemSal = ListMemSal.Where(m => m.SalaryStatus == 1).OrderBy(m => m.Member_Code).ToList();
  }
  if (Type == 3) {
    ListMemSal = ListMemSal.Where(m => m.SalaryStatus >= 2).OrderBy(m => m.Member_Code).ToList();
  }
}

var SelectedGroupByMember = ListMemSal.Where(m => m.SAL_ID == 0).GroupBy(m =>
  new {
    m.MEMBER_ID,
      m.Allowances,
      m.DeductionDetail,
      m.MemberDutyTiming,
      m.SAL_ID,
      m.Salary,
  }).ToDictionary(n => n.Key, n => n.ToList());
foreach(var mem in SelectedGroupByMember)
{
  IList < MetaDataCompany > OListAllowances = ReturnMemberAllowancesList(mem.Key.Allowances);
  IList < MetaDataCompany > OListDeductions = ReturnMemberDeductionsList(mem.Key.DeductionDetail);
  decimal DutyHours = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(mem.Key.MemberDutyTiming) ? (decimal) ReturnMemberDutyHours(mem.Key.MemberDutyTiming) : 0;

  if (mem.Key.SAL_ID == 0)
  {
    var IncAmount = HRFunctions.MemberIncrementByDate(mem.Key.MEMBER_ID, lastDayOfMonth.AddDays(1), DateTime.Now);
    var Advance = ReturnMemberExtraBalance(mem.Key.MEMBER_ID, Constants.ExtrasTypes.Advance, firstDayOfMonth, lastDayOfMonth);
    var LoanBalance = ReturnMemberExtraBalance(mem.Key.MEMBER_ID, Constants.ExtrasTypes.Loan, firstDayOfMonth, lastDayOfMonth);
    var Loan = PerMonthInstallment(mem.Key.MEMBER_ID);
    var OtherFineDeduction = ReturnMemberExtraBalance(mem.Key.MEMBER_ID, Constants.ExtrasTypes.OtherFineDeduction, firstDayOfMonth, lastDayOfMonth);
    var Bonus = ReturnMemberExtraBalance(mem.Key.MEMBER_ID, Constants.ExtrasTypes.Bonus, firstDayOfMonth, lastDayOfMonth);
    var Arrears = ReturnMemberExtraBalance(mem.Key.MEMBER_ID, Constants.ExtrasTypes.Arrears, firstDayOfMonth, lastDayOfMonth);
    double GPHours = ReturnGatePassHoursByDates(mem.Key.MEMBER_ID, FirstDay, endOfMonth).GPHours;
    TimeSpan GPTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(GPHours);
    var OvertimeDetail = ReturnOvertimeHoursByDates(mem.Key.MEMBER_ID, FirstDay, endOfMonth);
    TimeSpan OTTime = OvertimeDetail.OTTime;
    double OvertimeHours = OTTime.TotalHours;
    var OvertimeMinutes = OTTime;
    var OvertimeAmount = ReturnOvertimeAmount(_date, OvertimeMinutes, mem.Key.Salary, mem.Key.MEMBER_ID);
    var medInstallment = ReturnMedicalPerMonthInstallment(mem.Key.MEMBER_ID);
    var medBalance = ReturnMedicalSum(mem.Key.MEMBER_ID, Constants.ExtrasTypes.Medical, FirstDay, lastDayOfMonth, medInstallment);

    ListMemSal.Where(m => m.MEMBER_ID == mem.Key.MEMBER_ID).Select(c => {
      c.Salary = (c.Salary - IncAmount);
      c.LoanBalance = LoanBalance;
      c.AdvanceSum = Advance;
      c.LoanSum = Loan;
      c.BonusSum = Bonus;
      c.OtherFineDeductionSum = OtherFineDeduction;
      c.ArrearsSum = Arrears;
      c.MedicalSum = medBalance;
      c.oListAllDeductions = OListDeductions;
      c.oListAllowances = OListAllowances;
      c.DutyHours = DutyHours;
      c.GatePassHours = GPHours;
      c.OvertimeMinutes = OvertimeMinutes;
      c.OverTimeHoursTotal = OvertimeHours;
      c.OvertimeAmount = OvertimeAmount;
      return c;
    }).ToList();
  } else {
    ListMemSal.Where(m => m.MEMBER_ID == mem.Key.MEMBER_ID).Select(c => {
      c.oListAllDeductions = OListDeductions;
      c.oListAllowances = OListAllowances;
      c.DutyHours = DutyHours;
      return c;
    }).ToList();
  }
}
```

What I can do to optimized this request to less than 2 min?

Comment: I bet the bulk of this time is spent in database queries. To optimize them, use the tools of the DBMS.

Comment: @KlausGütter I understand. what's the best options with ORACLE database?

Comment: No matter how bad the query might be, it still doesn't make sense for it to take up to 30 min. Can you provide more information? A snippet of your code or something.

Comment: @SalihKavaf i have post the code. please suggest. thanks

Comment: Well... despite that this actually is an inefficient query; you have many nested loops when taking all that enumeration into account.

Comment: All that client side .Net code can probably be boiled down to a _much_ faster Oracle package or stored proc. Find an Oracle SQL developer and get them to help

Answer (score 0):

Your code will hardly run as fast as you want even after optimization. You should focus on optimizing the database. First make your table structure design conform to the third normal form, and add appropriate indexes according to your table structure. Then your sql statement can also be optimized. Finally, the fastest way to optimize query speed is to use local cache or distributed cache to participate in data storage, which will greatly improve your query efficiency.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/cache-policy

Comment: Oracle already has multiple caches. And how do you invalidate the cache when a single database  row is updated?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid  What you want to solve should be the problem of cache coherence. For the update operation, it is recommended that you update the DB first, and then delete the Cache. For this scenario, there are some suggestions for improvement:
1. Delay delete cache. This method can effectively prevent data inconsistency.
2. Monitor the database binlog incremental data update cache. This method is recommended , because you can focus more on business development.
3. Scheduled task incremental/full update cache data.